# Processed first, DOM or PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, html, dom

I have experimented with jQuery a while ago and it worked kinda neat. Now I created a site in php, with included header, footer, sidebar, you name it.

However, the jQuery doesn't seem to work AT ALL. I linked to the jquery file which I downloaded to my hard drive. I'm currently running this site on localhost (xampp).

Since none of the jQuery code is working (and I'm trying really basic stuff like a click handler to pop up an alert - just to make sure jQuery works) I was wondering if the DOM gets processed first and then the included PHP files.

Any help is appreciated, I just want some simple jQuery running on the site.

Thanks

EDIT: sample code

```
     $('document').ready(function() {

$("#header-photo").click(function() {
  alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});



 });
```

Linking the jQuery file:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

It's in the same folder.

Comment: Do you have any sample minimal code which doesn't work?

Comment: No, DOM is not processed first. You may want to provide some code context

Comment: What the alert shows when you run this script: `alert( typeof $)`

Comment: Are you loading the jQuery library before trying to run this code? Try opening the developer tools and checking for some errors in the console (F12 in chrome).

Comment: There is no alert at all, as if the jQuery does not work. And I am loading the jQuery file in the html <head>, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use it this way:

first ref to the jquery plugin:

```
<script src='path of your jquery plugin' type='text/javascript'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
  //  ^------^-------------------I think this is your problem 
  //  just remove the quotes " '  "

        $("#header-photo").click(function() {
            alert("Handler for .click() called.");
        });
    });
</script>
```

try this and see if this works.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I'll try to figure out what went wrong, if it was the jQuery src or the script src. I find this very odd. However, thank you a lot. Wish I could upvote you but apparently I can't yet.

Comment: Ah not a problem, I am GLAD this worked for u.

Answer (score 3):

PHP deals in text. It hands the text to the web server. The web server sends it to the browser. The browser interprets it as HTML/CSS/JS/etc. and builds a DOM from it.

So no. The DOM does not get processed first before the PHP runs.

(You might construct a DOM server side using PHP, but not with a simple include, that would require the explicit use of something like [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php))

Comment: Thanks, now I know this isn't the issue with the jQuery not working. Thanks for the downvote, whoever it is that wants to give new coders a warm welcome.

Comment: @cxn - +1'd that for ya. Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: @cxn - +1 from me also.  Too many uptight contributors on SO, but don't let that put you off!